# No Response, fetching data from remote Server : Using Sphinx SetServer

Tags: sphinx

I'm Using Sphinx 2.0.5-release On both Server .
Both Server have same indexers.I have Searchd running on both server . But I would like
to fetch Data of Server 1 from Server 2.
I used this particular code :

```
$cl = new SphinxClient;
$cl->SetServer(remote_sphinx_server,9312); (remote_sphinx_server : IP address of 2nd
```

Server)
    $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
    $result = $cl->Query("","$indexer");

But I Don't get any response .

Im getting error : connection to "Server 2 IP:9312" failed (errno=113, msg=No route to
host)

If i Use below code :

```
$cl = new SphinxClient;
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$result = $cl->Query("","$indexer");
```

I get proper response. As the data is coming from local Sphinx .

What can be the problem fetching data from remote Server ? Any Help is very much
appreciated .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- you may have multiple network interfaces on server 2 and you are using one the IPs that is not reachable by server 1
- check if firewall allows communication on port 9312
- check if searchd does run on server 2. Also, by default, searchd opens the port on all available interfaces, unless specified. Check searchd.log if reports any error about opening the port(s).